# MS excel 2013 related query

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2013

need help to achieve this. I have a spreadsheet with large number of rows and alot of columns . These rows consist of names, addresses, phone numbers etc. Column A, titled "first name" is blank. Column B, titled "Last Name" has both first and last names, middle initial and some have suffixes. . I need the first name and middle initial in Column A, last name and suffixes in column B and all the business names separated and put on a separate tab. All while taking the other 38 columns of info with each name. how this can be achieved via ms excel? can anybody assist?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far, as SO is not a free code writing service. In addition, separating out the various parts of the name is going to be hard.

Comment: Please update your question with some examples of your data.